# Preventing Duplicate insertion in datagridvew

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to check the item number received from a sender object; if the item number exists already, don't allow the user to enter it.

The code below didn't achieve this, but gave no error.

```
Public Sub ClickFunction1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim itemNo As Integer
        itemNo = sender.Name.Substring(3, sender.name.Length - 3)


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In ImsGrid1.Rows
            If row.Cells(4).Value = itemNo Then
                MsgBox(row.Cells(4).Value)
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Dim str As String = "select MedicineName,SellPrice,ItemNo,QtyAvailable from Items where ItemNo = '" & itemNo & "' "
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(str, con)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                Dim total As Double = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(1)
                ImsGrid1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0), dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(1), "1", total, dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(2), dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(3) - 1)

            End If
        Next



    End Sub
```

Comment: I would start by turning Option Strict On; then implement SQL parameters

Answer (score 0):

Two concepts to consider:

1. Never validate your data from your UI - use the underlying business objects. If you have to do something like `Cells(4)`, you should rethink your approach.
2. Validate duplicates in your data first (optional in-memory validation), then also have a unique constraint in DB, which would auto-validate your data on save (mandatory server side validation). Don't validate against the DB manually. Doing this has little sense, because data could have been added in between your validation and the actual save.

As suggested by @Plutonix, always use `Option Strict On`, it may grow your code a bit (so you may be tempted to keep it off), but this actually helps understand better when code complexity increases, and it's time to refactor.